How to share information between two classes in swift
I have view model as stateobject
@main
struct SwiftAuthTUApp: App {
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthViewModel()
    
    init() {
        
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(viewModel)
        }
    }
}

and some functions which get data from API
@MainActor
class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var authToken = ""
    @Published var currentUser: User?
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var password = ""

    
    @Published var hasError = false
    @Published var isSigningIn = false
    
    private let networkManager = NetworkManager.shared
    
    init() {
        Task {
            await fetchUser()
        }
    }
}

I get email and password from View
And there is a class which gets data from API
final class NetworkManager {
    //@StateObject var authModel = AuthViewModel()
    var token1: String = ""
    static let shared = NetworkManager ()
    //private let authModel = AuthViewModel.shared

    private init() {}
    
    func makeAPIRequestUserName<T: Decodable>(with url: String, objectToSend: Encodable, method: APIMethod, objectType: T.Type, completion: @escaping (Result<T>) -> Void) {
}
}

How can I get email and password from AuthModel in Network Manager functions?
Another problem, I call network manager functions from init of AuthModel, how can I make it in a correct way?
I tried to declare AuthModel as a state object in Network manager and as observed object, but can resolve issues with errors.

Don't use or try to use class AuthViewModel: ObservableObject in your NetworkManager.
You already have a networkManager in your AuthViewModel, you can
pass anything you want to its functions, eg networkManager.doSomething(email, password).

Tanks! But it can work until I have to get data trough Network Manager from another object, view for example. And I have to get token (email, password) from AuthModel and make calls like this networkManager.doSomething(token). I want the Network Manager can decide how it can make Auth itself.
